Catch UniqueViolationError in sqlalchemy
I have a FastAPI app and in some of the code I have the following code
from asyncpg.exceptions import UniqueViolationError
async def cache_data(data, embedding):

    async with asyncsessionmaker() as session:
        db_model = CacheModel(argument_call=data, embedding=embedding, model=CURRENT_EMBEDDING_MODEL)
        session.add(db_model)
        try:
            await session.commit()
        except UniqueViolationError as e:
            session.rollback()

The issue is, that an UniqueViolationError error is not caught.
If I use from sqlalchemy.exc import IntegrityError I can catch the error and the filter like

        except IntegrityError as e:
            if e.orig.sqlstate=='23505': #duplicated key error
                session.rollback()


but I feel it is a bit of a hack (and rather error-prone if sqlalchely decides to change the sqlstate).
How do I catch UniqueViolationError directly?

You can't trap it explicitly, because SQLALchemy traps it and replaces it with IntegrityError. You need to inspect the exception's orig attribute, as you are already doing.  sqlstate is part of the SQL standard, and the codes are defined by Postgres, not SQLAlchemy. Per the doc, they are " are less likely to change across PostgreSQL releases" so they should be reasonably stable, but you might want some unit tests to catch any changes.
